Alternative object to SlashCommandBuilder for hidden utility commands using discord.js
I have some utility files that work as command-events for specific interactions such as buttons that get pressed from other command interactions. The utility commands should NOT be accessible by a user through a slash-command, but rather only called by the event-handler.
At the moment, these files are in a subfolder that does not get searched by the command-deployment functions. Is there an alternative object creator function to SlashCommandBuilder that I can substitute it for in the 'data' part of the file (so that it does not register as a user-facing slash command)?
This way I would be able to stop relying on missing the util files from command deployment.
import { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonInteraction } from 'discord.js';

export const data = new SlashCommandBuilder() // What other function can I use?
    .setName('mywl')
    .setDescription('Utility file for wishlist button');

export async function execute(interaction: ButtonInteraction) {
    await interaction.reply({
        content: 'Hello ' + interaction.user.displayName,
        ephemeral: true,
    });
}

I have not found any info on discordjs.guide page.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, SlashCommandBuilder is a builder class provided by DiscordJS strictly to create public slash commands (which can then be given permission restrictions), sounds like you just need a function?

I suppose I could just omit the data constant completely, if it does not break anything.

The reason it needs to be a separate interaction event is that I return a modal, which I cannot do as a secondary reply.
